# TemplateDoesNotExist at /app/detail/3/

Tags: python, django

I got an error,

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /app/detail/3/ app/post_detail.html.
```

I wrote the following:

```
def top(request):
    content = POST.objects.order_by('-created_at')[:5]
    page = _get_page(blog_content, request.GET.get('page'))
    return render(request, 'top.html',{'content':content,"page":page})

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = POST

    def detail(request, pk):
        content = POST.objects.get(id=pk)
        return render(request, 'detail.html',{'content': content})
```

in `top.html`

```
<div>
         {% for content in page %}
            <h2>{{ content.title }}</h2>
            <p><a href="{% url 'detail' content.pk %}">SHOW DETAIL</a></p>
         {% endfor %}
</div>
```

in `detail.html`

```
<h2>{{ content.title }}</h2>
<p>{{ content.text }}</p>
```

When I access `top.html`, ordinary web site is shown, so it is ok. But when I put SHOW DETAIL links the error happens.

I did not write `post_detail.html` anywhere in my code, so I really cannot understand why `post_detail.html` causes the mistake.

As a test,I made `post_detail.html` in same directory with `top.html` and `detail.html`, but the same error happens. I want to make a system when I put SHOW DETAIL links, the content's detail is shown.

How should I fix this? What is wrong in my code?
After reading answer,I rewrote DetailView of views.py

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = POST
    template_name = 'detail.html'
```

but when I put SHOW DETAIL links, nothing is shown there.I wrote in detail.html

```
<h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
<p>{{ post.text }}</p>
```

Am I wrong to write the way of detail.html or views.py?How can I show detail's content?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a generic detail view for the POST detail. Generic views do not expect or use a `detail()` method, and either look for a template as specified in the `template_name` class attribute or the default which is `modelname_detail.html`.

You should either make your view a standard function view - like the "top" one - by moving the `detail` method out of that class; or, remove the method altogether (because it just does what the generic view does already) and either rename your template to `post_detail.html` or set `template_name = 'detail.html'`.

Comment: thx ur answer.I updated my question.If u know something please help me.

Comment: In a DetailView you can access the data via `object` or the name of the model, ie `POST` since your model name is in all capitals.

Comment: I wrote `<h2>{{ POST }}</h2>` or`<p>{{ POST.text }}</p>` but nothing is shown.Did I make a mistake something?